# public static Object reference not set error

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Issue: I have a `gridview` that i to reference. However when i try to reference it i get an error.

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> gridname was null.

main.aspx.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = datagridpopulate.Main("supplier", 0, null);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Weird point:
This was working yesterday and i made some changes to clean my code and now i cant figure out what ive changed thats made it stop working

Additional notes:
Ive tried to just print the control as a string to a popup window function i have. (`pop_up.main(GridView1.ToString());`) however it still states its null.

I would really appreciate your assistance :)

---- Error narrowed down to:
Okay so this is causing the error: 
`public static global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1;`
it worked when it was:
`protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1;`

The issue is i need to access the control from other class files. So it needs to be public static. How do get to keep it public static and also use object reference without the error?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to check if all the parameters are being properly passed to your `datagridpopulate.Main` function? From the looks of it, your function is not giving any data to your DataTable.

Comment: Hey, Yes. I have tried to just print the control in a popup window. 
pop_up.main(GridView1.ToString());
However it still says its not set/ is null.

So its unrelated to the dt

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Try this: `pop_up.main(Convert.ToString(GridView1));` and see what value do you get there

Comment: Hmm, there is no error. The popup comes up however it is blank. Im not sure what that indicates.

Comment: Well it indicates that your `GridView1` is empty and hence it returns nothing. Try seeing what values you get when your `GridView1` is populated with some data.

Comment: Thats interesting though. Shouldn't the gridview be empty until its bound to? which is what im trying to do?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354369/gridview-show-headers-on-empty-data-source

Comment: I cant bind data to it. thats the issue. i had a look at the link and it does not help

Comment: Thank you for trying kind sir

Comment: A similar problem to yours, hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825164/i-can-not-see-my-gridview-in-page-load

Comment: I narrowed it down. If you wanted to have a look at it?

Comment: Okay, please show what you have got till now on this problem?

Comment: Okay so this is causing the error: public static global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1; it worked when it was: protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1;

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: `> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
> 
> gridname was null.`

Comment: why is it `static`?

Comment: Okay, take a look at this question. It may help you achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165321/change-the-access-modifiers-of-asp-net-controls

Comment: @devio , If i dont have it as static i get this error in other code. Error` CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'About.suppliers_GridView1' `

Comment: Thank you Rahul, im having a look into that now

Comment: @RandomStuff Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Yes thank you. I ended up removing the static from my control. This created an access error which i fixed via creating instances and passing the control directly from the main form.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove About.

```
Create_P_O_functions.populatedatagrid(About.GridView1, "supplier", 0, null);
```

to

```
Create_P_O_functions.populatedatagrid(GridView1, "supplier", 0, null);
```

Your GridView is create two link above. I think as you, GridView is not on About page yet.

Comment: I removed it. However it did not fix it

Comment: I put the function within the page_load to help find where the issue is. I get the same error though. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: try to remove static of your function

Comment: I updated to not actually use that static function and im still getting the error

Comment: lol, with the code you have edit, the error is throw where ? on  GridView1.DataBind(); ? Your dt is fill ?

Comment: Its getting the error here: GridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: the dt is full though. It has 7 rows that ive just confirmed

Comment: Ive just dragged it out from the toolbox into the designer. It has autogenerate columns  true

Comment: Sorry I don't understand and haven't idea. Try to create another simple page and do the same thing, just add your gridview and call your method. I know you can access to the About.designer.vb in solution explorer  and look if gridview is declare in public ? Sorry I can't help you more :(

Comment: I narrowed it down. If you wanted to have a look at it?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a control in a static method. Remove the static no ? Why would you like the methds to be static ?

Comment: If i dont have it as static i get this error in other code. Error` CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'About.suppliers_GridView1' `

Comment: i think, you must correct this error and remove the static on the method. you can copy the line where the error cs0120 throw?

Comment: Okay, Should i then create a new question on this site with the new error and related info?

Comment: I ended up removing the static from my control. This created an access error which i fixed via creating instances and passing the control directly from the main form. Thank you